# How to configure Finger Print using api in android?

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

I would like to know that how can we support to configure finger print using Finger print api. I want to develop app from which user can configure his/her finger not from device setting.
Step:
1. Configure finger print from application.
2. Confirm registered finger print from application.

I have read Finger API and checked demo from below URL:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog

But this sample application demo demonstrate to authenticate finger print which is configured from device settings.

Please guide me how to configure and authenticate finger print from application.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to achieve using the API, believe me its a dump api with more restriction for developers (ios,android).
have a look at my question bellow url,
[myquestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971568/integrate-apple-touchid-or-samsung-finger-print-reader-with-my-app)