# Integrate apple TouchId or Samsung Finger print reader with my app

Tags: android, ios, touch-id, android-fingerprint-api

I am currently working on a mobile application for (Android, ios), which has the following requirement. Please tell me whether I can use the inbuilt finger print reader on latest smart phone, tablet to achieve my requirement.

I have a HRM System running on cloud, where I have the employee details,
Now i am developing an mobile app for employee time attendance, basically application will work in this following steps.

1. When employee open the app, it will show a finger print login.
2. Employee will tap the finger on the device, assume it has inbuilt fingerprint reader support.
3. The mobile application will get the fingerprint tapped and send it via web service to my cloud application for verification. If the verification is done successfully, the cloud app web service will return employee details for the matching finger print.and there after employees can do checkin, check out..
   (Assumption, I will be able to store finger prints,  relating it with my employee details in remote cloud app where authentication will       happen, so i think the device will let me access and save the finger print in remote servers)..

Answer (score 1):

The fingerprint reader on iOS devices can only return a yes/no that indicates whether the finger presented matched a fingerprint enrolled on the device.

Actual fingerprint data is stored securely in the hardware and is not available to the operating system or apps.

So, the short answer to your question is "No" on iOS.

From the [iOS Security Guide](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf)

> The fingerprint sensor is active only when the capacitive steel ring that surrounds the Home button detects the touch of a finger, which triggers the advanced imaging array to scan the finger and send the scan to the Secure Enclave.
>
> The raster scan is temporarily stored in encrypted memory within the Secure Enclave while being vectorized for analysis, and then it’s discarded. The analysis utilizes subdermal ridge flow angle mapping, which is a lossy process that discards minutia data that would be required to reconstruct the user’s actual fingerprint. The resulting map of nodes is stored without any identity information in an encrypted format that can only be read by the Secure Enclave, and is never sent to Apple or backed up to iCloud or iTunes.